# Governor signs executive order that bans mandated use of Covid-19 vaccine passports

Tags: covid-19

[Florida Governor signs executive order](https://www.cnn.com/world/live-news/coronavirus-pandemic-vaccine-updates-04-02-21/h_6eff715e8779572934605e94a01a7460) that bans mandated use of Covid-19 vaccine passports.  The Order, effective immediately, says vaccines are available but not mandated in the state and cites freedom and privacy concerns as the primary basis for the action.

**Given that Florida public schools require MMR vaccinations** (precedent?), how is it possible that such an order be lawful?

Other interesting & relevant precedent includes:

- [Jacobson vs. Massachussets:](https://www.history.com/news/smallpox-vaccine-supreme-court)  Supreme Court finds Vaccines can be mandatory
- Roman Catholic Diocese Of Brooklyn, New York v. Andrew M. Cuomo

I am having difficulty reconciling that the Supreme Court would uphold fines for not vaccinating, yet it concluded that NY state violated the right to congregate, despite a pandemic.

Comment: Without opining as to whether this is a good idea or within the governor's power, requiring something in one case but banning requiring it in another isn't incompatible.  For instance, you're _required_ to pay taxes on your income, but it's _illegal_ to require you to pay taxes to vote.

Comment: Mandatory Variola Vera vaccination was deemed constitutional more than 100 years ago. Need to look that up

Comment: @Trish  Is this what you would suggest? https://www.history.com/news/smallpox-vaccine-supreme-court

Comment: Yes, Jacobson was the case I remembered.

Answer (score 2):

As is the case in all 50 states there is statutory and constitutional law allowing governors to issue orders, pursuant to a declared emergency. The most recent order from Florida is [here](https://www.flgov.com/wp-content/uploads/orders/2021/EO_21-81.pdf). As usual, the order includes relevant citations, viz.

> Article IV,  Section 1 (a) of the Florida Constitution and by the
> [Florida Emergency Management Act](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0200-0299/0252/0252.html), as amended, and all other applicable
> laws

The section numbers and act names differ between the 50 states, but it reduces to the same logic as was employed to mandate different degrees of shut-down and mask-wearing. The emergency powers granted to the governor are very broad, and nothing within §252.36 hints that he overstepped his authority. Such powers might (rarely) be limited under a strict scrutiny judicial review, though such reviews in the age of covid have had limited success. There is no construal of "fundamental rights" whereby a limit on what government agencies can do could be called into question.

Governments have a well-established power to regulate businesses, which this order does. The order addresses a compelling government interest (assuring the privacy of individuals, and their ability to live their lives without discrimination, etc.), and it is narrowly tailored (temperature screening is still allowed). Perhaps a business can file a lawsuit, advancing a non-obvious argument that the order infringes on the liberty of businesses, but I doubt that it would gain judicial traction.

This is not to say that the Florida legislature could not pass a mandatory vaccination law coupled with a mandate to prove one's compliance: but they have not done so. So until a law is passed by the Florida Legislature that says otherwise (and its veto is overridden), the order is just as legal as its thousands of cousins have been.

Comment: Or perhaps a business can file a lawsuit, advancing the eminently obvious argument that the order infringes on the liberty of businesses to refuse to serve customers who endanger other occupants of their premises.